# append func gives a weird output

Tags: go

```
func main() {
    x := []int{}
    x = append(x, 0)
    x = append(x, 1)
    x = append(x, 2)
    y := append(x, 3)
    z := append(x, 4)
    fmt.Println(y, z)
}
```

> Why the output is this? [0 1 2 4] [0 1 2 4] Instead of this? [0 1 2 3]
> [0 1 2 4]

Comment: you must copy `x` to `y` and `z` then append

Comment: It's because you're overwritten the value, first copy then append (as Rahmat said)

Answer (score 1):

This would achieve your expected output of **[0 1 2 3] [0 1 2 4]**

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := []int{}
    x = append(x, 0)
    x = append(x, 1)
    x = append(x, 2)
    y := []int{}
    z := []int{}
    y = append(y, x...)
    z = append(z, x...)
    y = append(y, 3)
    z = append(z, 4)
    fmt.Println(y, z)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use this print statement, you can see append(x,3) and append(x,4) are returning the same pointer. That's the reason.

```
fmt.Printf("%p\n", &x)
fmt.Printf("%p\n", append(x, 3))
fmt.Printf("%p\n", append(x, 4))

0xc000010030
0xc00001c0a0
0xc00001c0a0
```